# Manga where a girl summons him to fight in a world he created in his head

Tags: story-identification, manga

There was a manga I read in middle school, but I forgot the name, and it didn’t have more than 3 books in the school. It’s about a guy who falls asleep and observes a world he created in his head, however one of the girls in this world summons him to fight in a battle, and then after which he wakes up next to her. This is as far as I can remember.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like ***[Welcome to Japan, Ms. Elf!](https://myanimelist.net/manga/117446/Nihon_e_Youkoso_Elf-san)***.

> Kazuhiro Kitase's only hobby is sleeping. Ever since he was young, he would enter a wondrous world within his dreams and go on thrilling adventures. One day, he goes on an adventure with an elf girl he became friends with in his dream world, but it's put to an abrupt halt when they both get scorched with a dragon's breath! As he wakes up from his dream, he notices a familiar figure sleeping next to him...the elf girl from his dreams?!
>
> Join Kazuhiro on his new adventures through Japan with Ms. Elf!

The MC is a Japanese salaryman who dreams about a JRPG-esque fantasy world when he goes to sleep at night. His character in that world is accompanied by an elf girl. Then one morning, he wakes up back in the real world, and see the elf girl in his bedroom with him.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just found it. It's called [*Desert Coral*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/341/Desert_Coral). It only had 3 volumes.

Plot description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_Coral):

> The manga takes place on the fantasy world of Orgos. Naoto Saki is the main character. Naoto was summoned to Orgos by the sorceress Lusia during a battle with her rival, Camu. Naoto, who previously visited the world many times before through his dreams as an invisible entity, gains a body and becomes visible to everyone else in Orgos. Naoto is initially not a welcome visitor among the rest of Lusia's group (who call themselves "Desert Coral"), but their aloof and unfriendly attitude gradually changes over time. The group known as Desert Coral never clearly state what their intentions are, but they primarily seem to be together in order to destroy the Elphis, a sadistic semi-immortal race that lives in the 'superior levels' of Orgos. It is later revealed that Naoto had visited this world before when he was a child. These prior visits by Naoto were apparently a means to escape reality after the death of his little sister. The world of Orgos is also revealed to be a dream created by Naoto to escape reality. It is later discovered that Lotus, Lusia's older brother and in one way or another related to every member of Desert Coral, is trying to steal the world of Orgos from Naoto.

(Click images for larger)

[image: Front cover of volume 1 showing a girl in a grey tank top, short shorts and boots holding a grey dragon]

[image: Back cover of volume 1 showing a boy sitting on the ground in front of a large brown animal with a girl perched on its back. The cover blurb is transcribed below]

The blurb reads:

> ### DAYDREAM BELIEVER
>
> Naoto Saki has an imagination so far-reaching that he has found an entire world within his daydreams.  He dreams of a fantasy world when he sleeps, a land of barren deserts and marvelous creatures.  One day, his elaborate reverie becomes reality when he is magically summoned into the very world of which he dreams.  Suddenly, a boy's fancies are transformed into panic, as Naoto is caught in a battle between the Elphis and the Sand Dusts.  He can feel pain here and experience real danger!  Returning home is his only wish, but the beautiful sorceress who summoned him has other plans...

Answer (score 0):

Fate Zero?
There's a fight where a servant (that is summoned by the master) fights in his head world.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. Are there any other details that you can [edit] in to help show why you believe this matches what the OP is looking for?